# How to use minimize from scipy correctly with multible variables?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have five variables that I would like to subject to `scipy.optimize.minimize` in order to find the solution I am seeking in terms of `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, and `E`. First, I imported `minimize` from `scipy` and defined the initial guesses (based on lab experiments, so they should be valid).

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

A0 = 1.90
B0 = 6.40
C0 = 11.7
D0 = 3.70
E0 = 2.50

ABCDE0 = [A0, B0, C0, D0, E0]
```

Second, I defined the individual functions that comprise the objective function conveniently named `Objective`. I also tried to combine `F`, `G`, `H`, and `I` into one function without any luck, so I decided to leave it like this for the time being.

```
def F(abcde):
    a, b, c, d, e = abcde
    return c - (b ** 2) / (a - e)

def G(abcde):
    a, b, c, d, e = abcde
    return (4 * e * ((a - e) * c - b ** 2)) / (a * c - b ** 2)

def H(abcde):
    a, b, c, d, e = abcde
    return b / (2 * (a - e))

def I(abcde):
    a, b, c, d, e = abcde
    return (2 * e * b) / (a * c - b ** 2)

def Objective(abcde):
    return (F(abcde) / G(abcde)) / (H(abcde) / I(abcde))
```

Third, I defined the `constraint` (i.e. `(F/G)/(H/I)=1`) and also the bounds named `bnds` to be `+/- 10%` of the initial guesses for the sake of simplicity.

```
def constraint(x):
    F = x[0]
    G = x[1]
    H = x[2]
    I = x[3]
    return (F / G) / (H / I) - 1

con = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint1}

min_per = 0.9
max_per = 1.1
bnds = ((A0*min_per, A0*max_per), (B0*min_per, B0*max_per), 
        (C0*min_per, C0*max_per), (D0*min_per, D0*max_per), 
        (E0*min_per, E0*max_per))
```

Fourth and finally, `minimize` provided me with a solution termed `sol`.

```
sol = minimize(Objective, ABCDE0, method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds, constraints=con1, options={'disp':True})
```

If sol was to be printed by `print(sol)`, the following message would appear.

```
Positive directional derivative for linesearch    (Exit mode 8)
            Current function value: 1.0
            Iterations: 18
            Function evaluations: 188
            Gradient evaluations: 14
     fun: 1.0
     jac: array([ 0.00000000e+00,  1.49011612e-08, -7.45058060e-09,  0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00])
 message: 'Positive directional derivative for linesearch'
    nfev: 188
     nit: 18
    njev: 14
  status: 8
 success: False
       x: array([ 2.09      ,  5.76      , 10.53      ,  4.07      ,  2.50000277])
```

To my novice mind, `constraint` appears to be the problem but I am not sure to due lack of experience with `minimize`.

- What I am doing wrong?
- Why is it not executing successfully?
- Is it better to use `root_scalar` as suggested by @fuglede in this scenario?
- Is it possible to include all the individual functions into one function to avoid making a mess?

Please be aware that `D0` and `d` are not included in any of the functions but is important in the grand schemes of things as one of the five independent variables.

Comment: If I'm understanding what you're trying to do correctly, your `constraint` should be a function of `a`, ...,`e`, and you would let `F = F([a, b, c, d, e])` instead (as an aside, note that using the name of a function for a variable as well is also asking for trouble). However, once you do so, what you effectively end up with is a constraint saying that the value of your objective is 1. That is, if you have any feasible solution, the objective will be 1, and the minimization is a bit dull. Is this what you want? If so, look into SciPy's root finding functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @fuglede. My `constraint` (`(F/G)/(H/I)=1`) is based on a symmetry assumption, so I need to make my data, which may be anywhere from 0.95 to 1.05, to become exactly 1 by varying the `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, and `E`. That is the reasoning behind the `constraint`. How can I implement `F = F([a, b, c, d, e])`? I can, of course, change the name to avoid confusion because I am in enough trouble as it is.

Comment: But are the `F`, `G`, `H`, and `I` in your constraint the same as in the definition of your objective? That is, are you trying to force your objective to be equal to one? And if so, since you are just trying to find a root of `objective - 1`, is there any reason to prefer `minimize` over e.g. `root_scalar`?

Comment: Yes, @fuglede, they are the same. I am also trying to force my objective to be equal to one, yes. No reason other than not knowing of the existence of `root_scalar` before you set me straight. So, in other words, you recommend to use `root_scalar` instead of `minimize` for scenarios such as the one I described?

Comment: I just realized that `root_scalar` (unsurprisingly, given its name) only eats scalar functions, but there are vector equivalents, and yes, they'll probably perform better. However, I also just realized that `Objective(ABCDE0)` actually is 1, so it seems you already have a solution?

Comment: In fact, it seems `Objective` is constantly equal to 1.

Comment: @fuglede, I realized the same as well. For the procedure I am doing, I need to convert my data to `A`, `B`, `C`,`D`, and `E` before I run `Objective`. It appears to be self-compensating, as this is yet another example of me overcomplicating things. I feel foolish, and for that I apologize. Thank you, though. If it is any consolidation, I did learn a few things due to your comments.

Comment: No worries; it's certainly not obvious from the given form that this would be the case. Let me attempt to consolidate these comments as an answer, so as to not have this appear as an unanswered question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things are going on here:

Firstly, as a matter of taste, I would probably have left the functions `F`, ..., `I` as having multiple inputs to avoid having to unpack the list. The objective function does need a list as its arguments though; i.e. you could do something like

```
def F(a, b, c, d, e):
    return c - (b ** 2) / (a - e)

...

def objective(abcde):
    return (F(*abcde) / G(*abcde)) / (H(*abcde) / I(*abcde))
```

That's just style. More importantly, your `constraint` method won't quite do what you want: As I understand, you want to evaluate the functions `F`, ..., `I` on the inputs, but that never happens; instead, the value of the variable `F` (which is an unfortunate name as it shadows the name of the function) ends up being simply `a`. Instead, you would do something like

```
def constraint(x):
    return (F(*x) / G(*x)) / (H(*x) / I(*x)) - 1
```

Now, `constraint(x)` is nothing but `objective(x) - 1`, so your constraints ends up stating that your `objective` must be equal to 1 at a feasible solution. This means that there's really not much optimization going on at all: Any feasible solution is optimal. While a priori `minimize` will indeed attempt to find a feasible solution for you, chances are that you'll have more luck trying to use some of the [root-finding capabilities](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#root-finding) of `scipy.optimize` as what you're doing is trying to find the roots of the function `objective - 1`.

Now finally, this actually turns out to be straightforward: Your function `objective` is equal to 1 wherever it's defined, so *any* input is a feasible solution: First, by writing `F = ((a-e)c - (b**2))/(a-e)`, note that `(a*c-b**2) / (4*e*(a-e))`. Then, `(F/G)*I = (2*e*b)/(4*e*(a-e)) = b/(2*(a-e)) = H`, so `1 = (F/G)*(I/H) = (F/G)/(H/I)`.

Comment: Thank you again, @fuglede! You taught me a lot via your previous comments that have now been articulated to perfection by this great summary.